# Installed DHCP Server but I cannot add a new scope

Tags: networking, dhcp, windows-server-2016, dhcp-server

I have added the DHCP Server role to my Server 2016 server.

Once installed I open the DHCP utility and expand my domain which lists IPv4 and IPv6

When I right click on IPv4 to set a scope the "New Scope" selection (along with Display Statistics and Set Predefined Options) are all greyed out.

Without the ability to add a scope my DHCP server can't serve IP's

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you confirmed the DHCP service is running and the server is authorized? It absolutely will not start if there is another DHCP server on the network.

Comment: It was authorized and started yes, I posted the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to go to the Server Manager > Tools > Computer Management In computer Management I expanded the Services and Applications section then expanded the Domain and right clicked on IPv4 and selected New Scope.

I also found that if I deauthorize the domain I can also add a new scope via the standard DHCP management screen.